# Extending object stored in HTML data-xxx element

Tags: jquery, extend, custom-data-attribute

Say I have the following simplified HTML form:

```
<form class = 'crud'>
  <div class = 'record' id='record_0'>
    <input id='testa_0' name='testa' class = 'crud-control'>
    <input id='testb_0' name='testb' class = 'crud-control'>
  </div>
  <div class = 'record' id='record_1'>
    <input id='testa_1' name='testa' class = 'crud-control'>
    <input id='testb_1' name='testb' class = 'crud-control'>
  </div>
  <div class = 'record' id='record_2'>
    <input id='testa_2' name='testa' class = 'crud-control'>
    <input id='testb_2' name='testb' class = 'crud-control'>
  </div>
</form>
```

Within the `data-update` attribute of the `div.record` elements, I'm storing the values modified/entered by the user in the input fields in an object `{testa: newvalue, testb: othervalue}` (until they are submitted to a database -- I'm skipping that submission step here for less code/complexity). I'm updating the data-update attribute using a jquery event handler:

```
  $( 'form.crud, table.crud' ).each(function(i,crud) {

    $(crud).find('.crud-control').change(function() {
      let $record = $($(this).closest( '.record' ));
      $record.data('update',{...$record.data('update'),...{[$(this).attr( 'name' )]:$(this).val()}});
      
    });

  });
```

This code works, but the `$record.data('update', ...` looks a little too complicated to be the best solution. Is there a better method to extend a data-xxx stored object with a key/value pair?

I tried:

```
$.extend( $record.data('update'), {[$(this).attr( 'name' )]:$(this).val()})
```

But this - for some reason, which I fail to understand - updates the `data-update` attribute for **all** `div.record`s and not only the one `closest()` to the `input.crud-control` updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. If you want to create a new object, it's basically a combination of the two:

```
$record.data(
    'update',
    // Create a new object
    {
        // Spread out the previous object's properties into it (if any)
        ...$record.data('update'),
        // Add the new property using computed property name syntax
        [$(this).attr( 'name' )]: $(this).val()
    }
);
```

But note that there's no reason for `$(this).attr('name')`, just use `this.name`, it's entirely standard. Similarly, `$(this).val()` is unnecessary with `input` elements, just `this.value` is sufficient.

With those applied:

```
$record.data(
    'update',
    // Create a new object
    {
        // Spread out the previous object's properties into it (if any)
        ...$record.data('update'),
        // Add the new property using computed property name syntax
        [this.name]: this.value
    }
);
```

Alternatively, you can update the existing object if present (since you're using jQuery's `data` method, it remains an object, it's not making a round-trip through text):

```
const object = $record.data("update") || {};
object[this.name] = this.value;
$record.data("update", object);
```

If you `data-update="{}"` to the HTML markup for the elements so you know the object will be there, then you can just do:

```
$record.data("update")[this.name] = this.value;
```

Again, since this is using jQuery's `data` (only getting *initial* values from the `data-update` attribute), the object is stored as an object, not text.

Comment: TJ - thanks so much for this... Obviously this: `$record.data( 'update' )[this.name] = this.value;` is the most elegant solution (I'm initiatlizing: all .record with `$crud.find( '.record' ).data({record:0, update:{}});` ... However, when I print out `console.log($('#record_0').data('update'),$('#record_1').data('update'),$('#record_2').data('update'))`... the data('update') for every .record are the same ... Maybe, I'm getting confused, but I was under the impression, that I could add a separate data-attribute to every DOM element... In that way, I wanted to store separete object per record

Comment: @DirkAlbrecht - The difference between the initialization I mentioned (`data-update="{}"` in the HTML) and what you did (`$crud.find( '.record' ).data({record:0, update:{}});`) is that the latter puts the **same object** on every element. The former (in the markup) is text that jQuery will convert to an object the first time `data` is used on that element, so each element gets its *own* object. But if all of these exist when your initialization code runs, I think you're right to do it with code, just slightly differently so they each ...

Comment: ... get their own: `$crud.find( '.record' ).each(function() { $(this).data({record:0, update:{}});});` :-)

Comment: TJ -- you got me once again ... not all the records are created, when the init code runs, as they are cloned later ... so here is what I'm doing during init and it works like a charm: `$crud.find('.record').attr('data-update','{}');` Thanks again!